# error in connection c# with oracle 11g 64 bit machine?

Tags: c#, oracle11g

My c# form has an error in the connection from c# with oracle 11g express edition, I've put my connection string in app.config file. This is my connection string:

```
add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=localhost;Password=LIB314;User ID=LIB_DB" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
```

When I want to run a query, it gives me error saying

> The 'MSDAORA' provider is not registered on the local machine

I use Windows 8.1 Pro x64... Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

UseORAOLEDB.ORACLE rather than MSDAORA.

Check below URL

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1022162

Thanks
Nipun

Comment: Nipun Ambastha ... i try this but i do not know how to use the oracle driver ... can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using OraOLEDB instead of MSDAORA. Register **OraOLEDB11.dll** using regsvr32.exe.

To do so, open command prompt and browse to the BIN folder of under your Oracle HOME's installation path (probably oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome1\BIN) and execute the following line:

```
>regsvr32.exe OraOLEDB11.dll
```

Also, ensure verify that the **PATH** variable is set properly and points to Oracle's installation path i.e.: C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome1\BIN

Comment: thank you Rahul Vijay Dawda ... after i do this i use OraOLEDB11.dll instead of MSDAORA or not?

Comment: You certainly should be using OraOLEDB instead of MSDAORA. For this error, I think MSDAORA is only supported with 32 bit applications and if yours is 64 bit, I sense that could be the reason why you're getting this error.

Comment: i try OraOLEDB but it gives me the same error? and my oracle home's path is not same as you write for this is my bin folder path "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>cd C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin"

Comment: What's the connectionString you're providing? It might be different for OraOLEDB. You can get the right connectionString from  www.connectionstrings.com. I hope you've the right driver installed. If not, search the Oracle docs and install the right driver for your need.

Comment: i use the above connection string ... and i download the oracle driver but i dont know how to use it? than you

Comment: You need to change your connectionString parameter PROVIDER from MSDAORA to OraOLEDB.Oracle. See http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/

Comment: The discussion seems to be getting really long. Could you post your code and the line that causes this error. And are you still still getting the MSDAORA error?

Comment: the problem not in my code iam sure ... if i change it to OraOLEDB.Oracle the error is changed to The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine